# Error while inflating custom layout on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I started doing an Android app a few days ago and I tried to make a custom widget to show data about each item in a list. It extends a Relative Layout.

I found this :
http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/05/26/custom-composite-android-component/

But my app doesn't launch anymore with this code.

Instead, I have thir error :

ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kpsolver/com.example.kpsolver.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.example.kpsolver.ItemEntry

In my activity :

```
private Problem pb;
private LinearLayout obj_list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pb = new Problem(100);

    obj_list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.objectsList);
    ItemEntry itEntry = (ItemEntry) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_entry, obj_list, false);
    obj_list.addView(itEntry);

}
```

ItemEntry.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ItemEntry extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView name, value, number, weight;
    boolean editable;

    public ItemEntry(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_entry, this);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textItemName);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textItemUse);
        value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textItemValue);
        weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textItemWeight);
    }

    public void setName(String str) {
        name.setText(str);
    }

    public void setValue(Integer v) {
        number.setText(v+" €");
    }
}
```

item_entry.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Nom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItemValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textItemWeight"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Val" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItemWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textItemUse"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textItemUse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonEditItem"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Poids" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonEditItem"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
obj_list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.objectsList);
ItemEntry itEntry = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_entry, null, false);
obj_list.addView(itEntry);
```

Though not completely sure about your error, because you didn't posted the complete XML

Comment: Well, Eclipse asks me to use a RelativeLayout var with this new cast, or to keep my ItemEntry cast.
It works with the RelativeLayout cast and var, but, obviously, I can't edit the specific data of what was supposed to be an ItemEntry ...

I added the whole XML. At first I didn't think its content would be relevant.

Comment: I tried the null pointer with a ItemEntry cast (as I said, Eclipse won't accept a RelativeLayout cas with a ItemEntry var). Same error.